# Durable goods in a (two sector) necolassical growth model

Tags: macroeconomics, optimization, dsge, solow, dynamic-optimization

i want to add a firm to a neoclassical growth model that produces a durable good which it rents out in each period to the consumers.
Right now i'm using the following approach:

- The firm maximizes: $\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \beta^j(p_tH_t-r_tK_t-w_tL_t)$

subject to the technology:   $A_tK^\alpha L^{1-\alpha} = N_t $
and s.t. stock evolves by:    $H_t=H_{t-1}(1-d)+N_{t-1}$

So the stock consists always of the depreciated stock from yesterday + the newly produced goods from yesterday.

Having the FOCs here and for the consumers leads to the same steady state conditions like in a normal growth model until i get to the stock equation of the durable good.
Here i don't know how to find the steady state.

Does someone know how to include such a company in a neoclassical growth model or knows literature about it?
How to solve such a model?
Optimally, in the end i want to include two types of consumers (high and low skilled) and two firms (a consumption good and the durable good firm).
Is there literature in that direction?

Usually in the literature the company produces new durable goods, sells them to household type a and they rent it out to other households (e.g. Housing Market Spillovers by Iacoviello and Neri).
But i'd prefer the company to be the owner of the stock of the durable good and renting it out (abstracting from households owning the firms).

I look forward to your help!